# data use in multiple ruby controller actions

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

We have a model, `Partner`. This partner sells `accounts`. Each month we recalculate a few things based on the number of accounts. I'd like to avoid repeating the same count in multiple model methods, and indeed the same multiple 'if' conditions, but need to be able to run them separately, so how do I dry up the code?

I'm thinking can I put them in an array, and then refer to it in relevant method, but not sure how to proceed. This is what it looks like at the moment...

```
  def recalculate_kickback
    accounts = self.accounts.count
    if accounts == 0
      self.update_attribute(:kickback, 0)
    elsif accounts.between?(1,5)
      self.update_attribute(:kickback, 10)
    elsif accounts.between?(5,15)
      self.update_attribute(:kickback, 15)
    else
      self.update_attribute(:kickback, 30)
    end
  end

  def recalculate_level
    accounts = self.accounts.count
    if accounts == 0
      self.update_attribute(:partner_level, 'None')
    elsif accounts.between?(1,5)
      self.update_attribute(:partner_level, 'Bronze')
    elsif accounts.between?(5,15)
      self.update_attribute(:partner_level, 'Silver')
    else
      self.update_attribute(:partner_level, 'Gold')
    end
  end
```

Comment: You might want to consider adding a `counter_cache` column to `Partner` for accounts

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could define the "levels" using constants:

```
LEVEL_NONE   = { kickback: 0, name: 'None' }.freeze
LEVEL_BRONZE = { kickback: 10, name: 'Bronze' }.freeze
LEVEL_SILVER = { kickback: 15, name: 'Silver' }.freeze
LEVEL_GOLD   = { kickback: 30, name: 'Gold' }.freeze
```

Write a method that returns the current level based on the accounts count:

```
def current_level
  case accounts.count
  when 0 then     LEVEL_NONE
  when 1..5 then  LEVEL_BRONZE
  when 5..15 then LEVEL_SILVER
  else            LEVEL_GOLD
  end
end
```

And use the returned hash in your methods:

```
def recalculate_kickback
  update_attribute(:kickback, current_level[:kickback])
end

def recalculate_level
  update_attribute(:partner_level, current_level[:name])
end
```

Comment: perfect. What does the 'freeze' do on the hash?

Comment: @GarethBurrows prevents you from accidentally modifying the hash, i.e. `LEVEL_NONE[:kickback] = 10` would result in a `RuntimeError`.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following.

You can either have two different methods recalculate_kickback and recalculate_level OR you can have a single method like recalculate_kickback_and_level which does the both updates at once.

I hope it helps you.

```
def recalculate_kickback
  kickback = 30
  accounts = self.accounts.count
  case accounts
  when 0
    kickback = 0
  when 1..5
    kickback = 10
  when 5..15
    kickback = 15
  else
    kickback = 30
  end
  self.update_attribute(:kickback => kickback)
end


def recalculate_level
  partner_level = 'Gold'
  accounts = self.accounts.count
  case accounts
  when 0
    partner_level = 'None'
  when 1..5
    partner_level = 'Bronze'
  when 5..15
    partner_level = 'Silver'
  else
    partner_level = 'Gold'
  end
  self.update_attribute(:partner_level => partner_level)
end




def recalculate_kickback_and_level
  kickback = 30
  partner_level = 'Gold'
  accounts = self.accounts.count
  case accounts
  when 0
    kickback = 0
    partner_level = 'None'
  when 1..5
      kickback = 10
    partner_level = 'Bronze'
  when 5..15
      kickback = 15
    partner_level = 'Silver'
  else
    kickback = 30
    partner_level = 'Gold'
  end
  self.update_attributes(:kickback => kickback, :partner_level => partner_level)
end
```

Comment: thats sort of what I said in the question. the methods need to be able to called separately. I'm looking for a way of avoiding the repetition of evaluating the account numbers